# Can you put steel strings on an acoustic guitar that came with bronze strings?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, strings

I know this sounds a bit dumb but I can't find an article anywhere and can't go to a guitar shop with the current situation and I thought now would be the perfect time to try different strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, bronze strings are actually steel strings too – the only difference is the winding material. But switching from bronze to steel should never cause too much problems – bronze is a bit more dense (good for bright, powerful sound projection) and has somewhat better oxidation properties than steel (except stainless), but the differences aren't huge, so if you want to give it a try, go ahead. I don't really see any advantage either, though.

Where there is a big difference is in the magnetic characteristics: on a guitar with magnetic PUs, switching from steel to bronze would be problematic, the bass strings would become much quieter in the electric signal. For for a pure acoustic or piëzo PUs, this doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes!

The bad thing would be to put steel strings on a classical guitar which should only be fitted with nylon strings. (The much higher tension of steel strings would bend the neck or pull out the bridge)

But steel strings and bronze are basically the same, so no problem there.